# I would like to get date from jQuery datepicker returned as text

Tags: jquery, text, datepicker, return

I have a jQuery's jQueryUI datepicker on a site. After the person chooses a date, I would like to display the date as text in a different div, such that:

1) Person chooses date and date appears in input box, then,
2) A new div shows and offers 'Pick a time on (selected date):'

jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function(){
      $('.date_panel,.time_panel').hide();

      $('.svc_button').click(function(){
            $('.svc_panel').fadeOut(function(){
            $('.date_panel').fadeIn();
            });
      });

      $('.time_button').click(function(){
            $('.time_panel').fadeIn(function(){
            });
      });

});
</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
</div>

<div class="date_panel">

<p>Click here to pick a date: <input id="datepicker" class="time_button" type="text"></p>

</div>

<div class="time_panel">

<p>Pick a time on: <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<span>" + .datepicker( "getDate" ) + "</span>");</script></p>
```

The time will be listed from a separate source.

Please, be explicit.

Comment: 1. show what you have, 2. What datetimepicker you use. 3. Be explicit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#datepicker').bind('change',function(){
              jQuery('#target').html(jQuery(this).val())
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5PqQb/

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

tried to work with the "onSelect" event?

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this addon to jquery-ui datepicker. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ It allow for the date and time to be picked. Good documentation and clean UI.

Comment: I'd already looked at that. The time is going to be pulled from a different source only after a date is chosen. It's for someone to choose specific times from specific dates, thus, if someone chooses 'Sunday,' zero available times will show. But if they choose 'Tuesday' and there are only a few time slots are available, only those times will show.